# Checking if a woocommerce product in a specific category is in a cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a code that lets me check your cart for a specific category. If the cart has any product of that specific category, then the script does something. How do I do this check?

Comment: You go through cart items and check their categories. Observing the contents of `WC()->cart` and using `has_term` should get you going.

Comment: @MSTannu i've tried this, the only thing is it gives me a giant array and I have to sort through it with a foreach loop which I can't have. I need some type of way that'll let me scan the entire carts contents, and if a certain product is in there then X happens. Best case scenario I can just search by category, but if it comes to it, I can search specific by product id. like if($product = 60){ X }

Comment: The optimal way to `scan the entire carts contents` is to `sort through it with a foreach loop`. Why the reluctance to do it?